# currency field validation for auto fields javascript

Tags: javascript

I have price field in my form. `Any number` of price fields may come. I have to check `currency validation` for all the price fields. It should allow numbers, decimal point (.), commas (,) and us dollar symbol ($) only. How can i do that?

Comment: use RegExp. `/[0-9\.,\$]/` something like that should do for you.

Answer (score 0):

Mask Input with accounting.js jquery plugin.
http://josscrowcroft.github.com/accounting.js/

Comment: I need not to convert to currency. I just need to validate that the entered value is a valid currency.

Comment: I'm sorry. My english not better. I dont understand your question.